# Tornado mysteriously hanging after an async operation -- how can I debug?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

Our app uses a fair few network calls (it's built on top of a third-party REST API), so we're using a lot of asynchronous operations to keep the system responsive. (Using Swirl to stay sane, since the app was written before `tornado.gen` came about). So when the need arose to do a little geocoding, we figured it would be trivial -- throw in a couple of async calls to another external API, and we'd be golden.

Somehow, our async code is mysteriously hanging Tornado -- the process is still running, but it won't respond to requests or output anything to the logs. Worse, when we take the third-party server out of the equation entirely, it still hangs -- it seems to lock up some arbitrary period after the async request returns.

Here's some stub code that replicates the problem:

```
def async_geocode(lat, lon, callback, fields=('city', 'country')):
    '''Translates lat and lon into human-readable geographic info'''
    iol = IOLoop.instance()
    iol.add_timeout(time.time() + 1, lambda: callback("(unknown)"))
```

And here's the test that usually (but not always -- that's how it got to production in the first place) catches it:

```
class UtilTest(tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase):

    def get_new_ioloop(self):
        '''Ensure that any test code uses the right IOLoop, since the code
        it tests will use the singleton.'''
        return tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    def test_async_geocode(self):
        # Yahoo gives (-122.419644, 37.777125) for SF, so we expect it to
        # reverse geocode to SF too...
        async_geocode(lat=37.777, lon=-122.419, callback=self.stop,
                      fields=('city', 'country'))
        result = self.wait(timeout=4)
        self.assertEquals(result, u"San Francisco, United States")
        # Now test if it's hanging (or has hung) the IOLoop on finding London
        async_geocode(lat=51.506, lon=-0.127, callback=self.stop,
                      fields=('city',))
        result = self.wait(timeout=5)
        self.assertEquals(result, u"London")
        # Test it fails gracefully
        async_geocode(lat=0.00, lon=0.00, callback=self.stop,
                      fields=('city',))
        result = self.wait(timeout=6)
        self.assertEquals(result, u"(unknown)")

    def test_async_geocode2(self):
        async_geocode(lat=37.777, lon=-122.419, callback=self.stop,
                      fields=('city', 'state', 'country'))
        result = self.wait(timeout=7)
        self.assertEquals(result, u"San Francisco, California, United States")
        async_geocode(lat=51.506325, lon=-0.127144, callback=self.stop,
                      fields=('city', 'state', 'country'))
        result = self.wait(timeout=8)
        self.io_loop.add_timeout(time.time() + 8, lambda: self.stop(True))
        still_running = self.wait(timeout=9)
        self.assert_(still_running)
```

Note that the first test almost always passes, and it's the second test (and its call to `async_geocode`) that usually fails.

Edited to add: Note also that we have lots of similarly asynchronous calls to our other third-party API which are working absolutely fine.

(For completeness, here's the full implementation of `async_geocode` and its helper class (although the stub above replicates the problem)):

```
def async_geocode(lat, lon, callback, fields=('city', 'country')):
    '''Use AsyncGeocoder to do the work.'''
    geo = AsyncGeocoder(lat, lon, callback, fields)
    geo.geocode()


class AsyncGeocoder(object):
    '''
    Reverse-geocode to as specific a level as possible

    Calls Yahoo! PlaceFinder for reverse geocoding. Takes a lat, lon, and
    callback function (to call with the result string when the request
    completes), and optionally a sequence of fields to return, in decreasing
    order of specificity (e.g. street, neighborhood, city, country)

    NB: Does not do anything intelligent with the geocoded data -- just returns
    the first result found.
    '''

    url = "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode"

    def __init__(self, lat, lon, callback, fields, ioloop=None):
        self.lat, self.lon = lat, lon
        self.callback = callback
        self.fields = fields
        self.io_loop = ioloop or IOLoop.instance()
        self._client = AsyncHTTPClient(io_loop=self.io_loop)

    def geocode(self):
        params = urllib.urlencode({
            'q': '{0}, {1}'.format(self.lat, self.lon),
            'flags': 'J', 'gflags': 'R'
        })

        tgt_url = self.url + "?" + params
        self._client.fetch(tgt_url, self.geocode_cb)

    def geocode_cb(self, response):
        geodata = json_decode(response.body)
        try:
            geodata = geodata['ResultSet']['Results'][0]
        except IndexError:
            # Response didn't contain anything
            result_string = ""
        else:
            results = []
            for f in self.fields:
                val = geodata.get(f, None)
                if val:
                    results.append(val)
            result_string = ", ".join(results)

        if result_string == '':
            # This can happen if the response was empty _or_ if 
            # the requested fields weren't in it. Regardless, 
            # the user needs to see *something*
            result_string = "(unknown)"

        self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda: self.callback(result_string))
```

**Edit**: So after quite a bit of tedious debugging and logging the situations in which the system fails over a few days, it turns out that, as the accepted answer points out, my test was failing for unrelated reasons. It also turns out that the reason it was hanging was nothing to do with the IOLoop, but rather that one of the coroutines in question was immediately hanging waiting for a database lock.

Sorry for the mis-targeted question, and thank you all for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second test appears to failing because of this part:

```
self.io_loop.add_timeout(time.time() + 8, lambda: self.stop(True))
still_running = self.wait(timeout=9)
self.assert_(still_running)
```

when you add a timeout to the IOLoop through `self.wait`, that timeout is not cleared when `self.stop` is called, as far as I can tell. I.E. your first timeout is persisting, and when you sleep the IOLoop for 8 seconds, it triggers.

I doubt any of that is related to your original problem.

Comment: You're absolutely right that that was causing the test to fail. And equally right that my original problem had nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sadly I have no idea how to start debugging your actual problem.